# QLPreviewController Doesn't Show Document

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to get QLPreviewController to display a pdf document. When the document is saved to the device the file location string (within the documents folder) is recorded. I later create a URL from that file location string with URL (fileURLWithPath: location) and use that as input for a QLPreviewController data source. Up until now, that worked and the quick look would present with the document properly.

Unfortunately, that no longer works. I updated to Xcode 11 (swift 5.1) this morning, and now my QLPreview controller doesn't show the document. It still presents, but with a gray background that says "Document name" and "pdf document." If I click the share button and go to print it, the print preview correctly shows my file (and pushing print does print the correct file in its entirety) so I know the file is there, and is readable. It just won't display in the QLPreviewController for some reason. (This error is also reported [on the apple developer forums](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/119368), but nobody there had any suggestions to fix it other than trying on a non-simulator device which I've already done.)

The debug text from Xcode is as follows:

```
Could not create FPSandboxingURLWrapper with url: file:///Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F69CC8ED-C164-4E36-946F-E675C7FC7365/data/Containers/Data/Application/739F1371-1A79-41B1-8FF5-E8ACC0FEA976/Documents/mydoc.pdf, error: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=22 "couldn't issue sandbox extension com.apple.app-sandbox.read for '/Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F69CC8ED-C164-4E36-946F-E675C7FC7365/data/Containers/Data/Application/739F1371-1A79-41B1-8FF5-E8ACC0FEA976/Documents/mydoc.pdf': Invalid argument" UserInfo={NSDescription=couldn't issue sandbox extension com.apple.app-sandbox.read for '/Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/F69CC8ED-C164-4E36-946F-E675C7FC7365/data/Containers/Data/Application/739F1371-1A79-41B1-8FF5-E8ACC0FEA976/Documents/mydoc.pdf': Invalid argument}
```

Something else that might be of note: I was getting similar error messages before in a previous iteration of my code, and I figured out the problem was that I was passing a url from string instead of a fileurlfrompath, and changing to that fixed my problem. I suspect this is just a different problem, but the error messages were similar so I thought id mention it. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.